# how to pass multiple data- id in a modal body

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

Suppose I have multiple order id

```
$order_id='12345566778';
$prod_id='126778899';
$sell_id='373462562363';
```

While I select particular orderid I want it to pass in php variable which is under the modal body of popup let me know how to do it I am struggling with this

```
<a rel="dialog" data-toggle="modal" data-id="<?=$order_id?>" href="#mymodal" data-target="#myModal" >
    <?php echo "<br> $order_id </br>";?>
</a>

<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">×</span>
                </button>

                <table class="table table-hover table-bordered" >
                    <tr style=" background-color:#00AAAD; color:#FFF; ">
                        <div class="modal-body">

                            i want to get that order id under php variable which i select           
                            here i want to display the data
                        </div>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </div>

            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">
                Close
                </button>
            </div>
        </div><!-- /.modal-content -->
    </div><!-- /.modal-dialog -->
</div>
```

Comment: help me out with this i am struggling

Comment: You do not know php i see. Javascript is Client Side and ok, php is server side and is a scripting language, when you see your Page php as already stopped to run. To achieve what you want you need to make an Ajax call to another php page or submitting a form or changing the page using a Get variable.

Comment: You can't as PHP runs at server and popups are in the browser way later.

Comment: you can fetch data-id using javascript and display in model

Comment: how can i do it

Comment: can i pass multiple data-id suppose one order_id and one prod_id at a time

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `jQuery.data()` method to do this. Try this way:

**HTML code**

```
<a class="open-my-modal" rel="dialog" data-toggle="modal" data-id="<?=$order_id?>" data-prod-id="<?=$prod_id?>" data-sell-id="<?=$sell_id?>" href="#mymodal" data-target="#myModal" >
    <?php echo "<br> $order_id </br>";?>
</a>

<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">×</span>
                </button>

                <table class="table table-hover table-bordered" >
                    <tr style=" background-color:#00AAAD; color:#FFF; ">
                        <div class="modal-body">

                            <div id='order-id'></div>
                            <div id='prod-id'></div>
                            <div id='sell-id'></div>
                        </div>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </div>

            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">
                Close
                </button>
            </div>
        </div><!-- /.modal-content -->
    </div><!-- /.modal-dialog -->
</div>
```

**jQuery Code**

```
$(document).ready(function () {             
    $('.open-my-modal').click(function(){
        $('#order-id').html($(this).data('id'));
        $('#prod-id').html($(this).data('prod-id'));
        $('#sell-id').html($(this).data('sell-id'));

         // show Modal
         $('#myModal').modal('show');
    });
});
```

Comment: you are most welcome. It would be great if you give me a up vote :)

Answer (score 0):

Theres a way you can do this..
The ways is really simple just use variable passing using get or post method.
in action tag put the address of the current page.

```
<form action='your_current_page' method='post'>
  <select name='id' id='order_id'>
    <option value='12345566778'>12345566778</option>
    <option value='126778899'>126778899</option>
    <option value='373462562363'>373462562363</option>
   </select>
<?php
  $order_id=$_POST['id']; # id is you name attribute in select tag
?>
```

this is how you going to pass variables from html to php...
hope this solves the problem..